# No puedo procesar formulario

Tags: php, javascript, paypal

Lo que quiero hacer es sacar los emails de mi tabla de usuarios para luego enviar los valores a Paypal y estos sean procesados por la empresa de Paypal.
Estuve haciendo varios testeos, lo que me di cuenta que si lo hago con un solo email sin realizar la consulta a mi tabla si me procesa bien los datos.
Pero como quiero sacar lo emails de mi tabla por usuario osea un usuario por consulta para que esté me envíe el valor del usuario a Paypal y este me lo procese ya no me lo procesa.
Este es el ejemplo de mail usuario sin consulta el cual si me resultó:
//Este va en alguna parte del codigo php

```
$emaildeusuario:ejemplo@gmail.com
```

Y este en la parte del codigo html:

```
   <input name="business" type="hidden" value= "<?php echo $emaildeusuario; ?>" />
```

Ahora el ejemplo de mail usuario con consulta el cual ya no me resultó:
//Este va en alguna parte del codigo php

```
$usuario = "bicholo";


$sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios_establecidos where usuarios_establecidos = '".$usuario ."' ";

$result = $conn->query($sql);



if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

  // output data of each row

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        

$email = $row['email'];

  }
```

Y este en la parte del codigo html:

```
   <input name="business" type="text" value= "<?php print_r($email); ?> " />
```

Si me pone el valor de la variable email en el campo input del formulario pero Paypal ya no me lo procesa.

Answer (score 0):

Talvez necesite convertir el array en string, pero no logro
sacar solo la variable $row['email']; me la muestra vacía, pero si la pongo así $email = implode($row); me muestra todos los registros que extrae el bucle while.
Cuando me interesa solo sacar el email del array, y convertir a string

```
// output data of each row

  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {


$email = implode( $row["email"]); 

echo $email;

     





  }
```